# How to stop moving UIVIew on keyboard appearing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

Whenever I click on a `UITextField`, my `UIView` will move up. How can I stop this?

Comment: by default it's not moving. there is some code in your controller that reacts for onKeyboardShow event.

Comment: Your views appear to be contained in a UIScrollView  and your view is being moved as the textfield viewable are is not at such height to cover keyboard height .

Comment: can you show ur viewcontroller code

Answer (score 0):

There could be a chance of one of below.

1. If UIView is inside(contained) by ScrollView, then set the contentSize to have more height `CGSize siz=sv.frame.size; siz.height+=300;sv.contentSize=siz;` where 300 is keyboard height.
2. If there is some code to handle keyboard sizing then search for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and comment the lines with addobserver, removerobserver in them